# How to have detailed JS console in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

In Chrome, when we do

```
console.log(document.styleSheets);
```

it will show the whole object elements and we can traverse through it.

In Firebug, it shows the message, when I click on it, it opens in DOM inspector which lets me browse the children.

But when I do this:

```
for (var S = 0; S < document.styleSheets.length; S++){
    if(document.styleSheets[S][cssRuleCode]){
        for(var n = 0; n < document.styleSheets[S][cssRuleCode].length; n++) {
            console.log(document.styleSheets[S][cssRuleCode][n]);
```

Firebug shows

```
CSSStyleRule { constructor=CSSStyleRule, parentStyleSheet=CSSStyleSheet, style=CSSStyleDeclaration, more...}
```

and when I click on it, it just opens up the CSS entry, no children information.

How do I get detailed object representation in JS console in Firefox (with or without Firebug)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the link in the console, then click `Inspect in DOM tab`.